# Libgdx. Converting Screen Click Coordinates into World Coordinates for 2D Game

Tags: android, libgdx, mobile

I'm using the `InputHandler`'s `touchdown` method. It gives me my `screenX` and `screenY`. Is there a simple way to convert screenX and screenY to world coordinates? By my understanding, `InputHandler` returns the coordinates in relation to your screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

Take your camera matrix and unproject it (or invert it). This can be done in libgdx like so:

```
 Vector3 worldCoordinates = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
 camera.unproject(worldCoordinates);
```

[The documenation can be found here.](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.html)

Comment: Ok thanks. It works exactly like I wanted it. Very useful information!

Comment: @PatrickJean If this answered your question, please accept it on the left hand side so other users can see this in the future.